# Как в Elasticsearch удалить документы соответствующие условию?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

У меня в Python скрипте раньше использовался elasticutils.
Сейчас переписываю под использование модуля elasticsearch-dsl

Вот старый код:

```
from elasticutils import get_es

es = get_es(urls=config.ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOSTS, timeout=timeout)
es.delete_by_query(
            'posts',
            'post',
            {'query': {'term': {'user_id': user.id}}})
```

В elasticsearch-dsl нет ничего для такой операции.

Как удалить документы по условию модулем elasticsearch?
Используется Elasticsearch 2.4.
Модуль delete_by_query выпилен из второго эластика, впиливать его обратно не желательно.

Насколько понимаю нужно удалять через bulk. Но не понимаю как построить запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Решение подсказали на Toster https://toster.ru/q/488358

```
def _make_queryes(es, q, index, doc_type):
    """Return generator of queryes to delete docs"""
    res = helpers.scan(es,
                       query=q,
                       index=index,
                       doc_type=doc_type)
    for r in res:
        yield {"_op_type": "delete",
               "_index": r["_index"],
               "_type": r["_type"],
               "_id": r["_id"]}


def bulk_delete(index, doc_type, query):
    """Delete all docs that match the query condition"""
    es = get_indexer()
    k = (i for i in _make_queryes(es, query, index, doc_type))
    helpers.bulk(es, k, index=index, doc_type=doc_type)


bulk_delete("posts",
            "post",
            {'query': {'term': {'user_id': user.id}}})
```